# How to scrape link title over many pages and through specified tab

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am having trouble figuring out how to use BeautifulSoup to scrape all 100 link titles on the page since it is under "a href = ....." . I have tried the below code but it returns a blank.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
import bs4


url = 'https://www150.statcan.gc.ca/n1/en/type/data?count=100'
page = urlopen(url)
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page,'html.parser')
title = soup.find_all('a')
```

Additionally, is there a way to ensure I am scraping everything under the "Tables (8898)" tabs? Thanks in advance!

```
Link: 

https://www150.statcan.gc.ca/n1/en/type/data?count=100
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The link you provided is loading it's contents with async javascript requests. So when you exec `page = urlopen(url)` it is only fetching the empty HTML and javascript blocks.

You need to use a browser to execute js to load page contents. You can checkout this link to learn how to do it: https://towardsdatascience.com/web-scraping-using-selenium-python-8a60f4cf40ab